# How to automatically kill Java (PID) process when the maven/jenkins build was stopped/aborted externally?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, automation

I aborted Jenkins job(Maven build) manually but the java process was still active and running until I force exit (manually killed ) java process.

Maven Plugin using :

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I tried running the mvn test -Dxxxx locally , when I ctrl+C terminate it, the java session is still active. then I have to kill java process manually using command taskkill /f /im java.exe

Seems I am missing a maven plugin which exit/kill the java process when the build is aborted.

I also tried with plugin below:

```
      <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                    <configuration>      
                         <shutdown>exit</shutdown>
                    </configuration>                  
       </plugin>
```

But It DIDN'T WORK.

Also tried with couple of more plugins and methods with runtime i.e. addshutdownhook, but No luck!

EDITED: Plugin in pom.xml

```
 <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environment>uat</environment>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>tag</name>
                            <value>login</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: If maven is terminated,java process related to project is also terminated, there is no need to kill .

Comment: That means Maven is not properly terminated otherwise there won't be any java process active or running after aborting the jenkins job. what is missing which is not terminating Maven properly ? @Sambit

Comment: Try to run locally and see whether maven is terminated or not.

Comment: I tried running it locally and terminating ctrl+C and maven isn't terminated(app is still running) @Sambit

Comment: Do you have this project in github so that I can have a look.

Comment: I do but it can't be accessed. though I am using the only plugin [edited] above @Sambit